# Setting attribute of item in observer?

Tags: event-observer, product-attribute

In Magento 1.9.3 I created a custom product attribute called **is_sample**. Its a text field. When a product is added to the cart I am trying to set that value in my bbserver, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
$item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
$item->setCustomPrice($price); // works
$item->setIsSample('1'); // does NOT work
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

**Magento 1.9.3.x**

Comment: Did you create any field is_sample on your quote item table? Because $item is a instance of quote item not product.

Comment: /* Get all the items in the cart */
$cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
/* Iterate through the items */
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    /* Load the product and get the custom attribute */
    Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getMyCustomAttribute());
}   You can get product detail in session do you try above code ?

Comment: @Sukumar Gorai: No I didnt, I was thinking that if it is created as a product attribute it will be taken over to the quote item as well?

Comment: No it will not. Either you need to create one field or you need to use additional_options in cart for each items if you want.

Comment: What do you mean with additional_options? Do you have a code example?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. Its working for me:

```
$additionalOptions = array(
    array(
        'code'  => 'is_sample',
        'label' => 'Is Sample',
        'value' => 'Yes'
    )
);
$item->addOption(
    array(
         'code'  => 'additional_options',
         'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
    )
);
```

Comment: Doesnt work :( ... how would I add the attribute to the item another way and so that it is available in checkout?

Comment: It should add the option to your cart as other. It doesn't? I have used this code before and still its working fine for me. I have used checkout_cart_add_after event.

Comment: I am using checkout_cart_product_add_after ... did you mean that?

Comment: Yes right. So its not working for you?

Comment: Now its working, good! The last thing I need to do is, to access that with the owebia shipping extension. This is the doc: https://owebia.com/os2/en/doc

I tried with condition `{count items where product.additional_options.is_sample=='1'} == {cart.qty}` or `"{count items where item.additional_options.is_sample=='1'} == {cart.qty}"` but it does not recognize it. I am using '1' as value when I add the additional_options. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you add this condition?

Comment: In the observer event...did you see my previous comment?

Comment: Yes I have checked but what condition do you want?

Comment: I want to be able to evaluate that with the owebia shipping extension, thats all whats left. If there are only items in the cart with is_sample set to 1, shipping fee is 0.

Comment: According to the answer you set 'Yes' and you are checking 1 in your condition.

Comment: No, I changed your Yes to 1 in my code :)

Comment: You will not get value like this item.additional_options.is_sample as magento saves the data in table in json format. You need to retrieve the value from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80598/discussion-between-arnie-and-sukumar-gorai).